# How do I create an inspection in IntelliJ for relative imports in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, intellij-inspections

I create a new `User defined` inspection, using `Structural search`, and put this in the `Search template`:

```
from '../
```

But I can't get it to work. Neither do these:

```
"from '../"

import $something$ from '../$path$'
```

I can't even get a hit when is try this:

```
from
```

What do I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Structural search`. Add a `RegExp` instead

```
from '\.\./
```